# How to insert records into SQL query result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am querying a TEMP table whereby I'm needing to insert records for each TYPE even though no TYPE value may exist.  I need there to be 0 DATA record for each of the TYPES in each ACTIVITY MONTH.  So each month needs to have 4 TYPES (PIF, WP, EP and LR). Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT [Agency Code], [Agency Name], [Data], [Activity Month],
    CASE
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'PIF' 
        WHEN RN = 2 THEN 'WP' 
        WHEN RN = 3 THEN 'EP'
        WHEN RN = 4 THEN 'LR'
    END as [Type]
FROM #tempMonthlyResults_NLA
ORDER BY [Agency Code] asc, [Activity Month] asc, RN asc;
```

Here is what I need for my result set to look like:

[image]

Here is what my query result set looks like now:

[image]

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). It's much easier for us to help you if you provide DDL and sample data in a usable form.

Comment: Habo, I didn't post my code as an image but the results as an image. The SQL code is in the code block

Comment: I would make it clear that by 'Type' you mean a user defined field (column) as opposed to a TSQL type such as bigint or datetime

Comment: @Melinda I was thinking more along the lines of `declare @MySampleTable as Table ( Id Int Identity, AgencyShoeSize VarChar(9), ... ); insert into @MySampleTable ( AgencyShoeSize, ... ) values ( '7EEE', ... ), ( ... );`. That way we all know what datatype `RN` and the other columns are and can write and test queries easily.

Comment: And without sample data we are left guessing what you are trying accomplish. It seems the query and your desire are different but who knows why?

Comment: Allow me to respectfully suggest reading [ask] and [mcve], @Melinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a FULL OUTER JOIN to a table or CTE of the 4 types, CROSS JOINed to the DISTINCT activity months.

That, or you can probably do this with a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Tab, thank you for the info.  I was able to finally get that with your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an RN_TYPE lookup table that contains the values and associated code.

```
RN_TYPE table:
RNID int
Type char(3)

RNID   Type
1      PIF
2      WP
3      EP
4      LR
```

Then using the suggestion from @Tab create a query using

```
FROM RN_TYPE LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempMonthlyResults_NLA on RN_TYPE.RNID=#tempMonthlyResults_NLA.RN
```

That way you will always return the Types.

Comment: Thank you, Jon.  Appreciated your help.